# Do plant cells recycle carbon dioxide from their respiration during photosynthesis?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, cellular-respiration

It seems one of my colleague's biology textbook claims that plant cells, with presence of light, feed back 100% of carbon dioxide molecules from their respiration into photosynthesis. Can you say that carbon dioxide molecules, gas or dissolved, get transferred from the mitochondria to the chloroplast?

Comment: Please provide a source for your colleague's text book and quote verbatim what it says. That way we can help clarify questions that may arise from misunderstanding what the author intends.

Comment: Will do that tomorrow, but it's in Korean so it has to undergo translation. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @tyersome It does I think! Gaseous carbon dioxide must be no exception from random diffusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2884119/
This paper found mitochondria move to be next to chloroplasts when exposed to light. So carbon dioxide is  more likely to be recycled in lighted conditions.

Comment: Wow, it's a whole new perspective!